# Combination of subarrays

Tags: java

Not sure if this has been asked already but I'm having trouble printing combinations of subarrays.

Given say

```
int[][] x= {{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7}};
```

print all valid combinations by choosing one int from each subarray.
some valid outputs are:

```
1,3,6   
1,3,7  
1,4,6  
1,4,7
..
... etc
```

SO far my code looks like

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

int[][] x= {{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7}};
for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
 for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
    for (int k = 0; k < 2; k++){                
            System.out.println(x[0][i]+" " + x[1][j] +" "+ x[2][k]);            
    }
}
```

My code is throwing an exeption indexoutofbounds. I'm not sure where I'm going out of bounds. I know its the naive solution and brute force and theres prob a better way to solve it but this solution is the first that came across my mind.

Comment: looks like you are going out of bounds when you call x[0] [i], the length of x is 3 but the first array only has two elements in it.

Comment: x[0] [j] also goes out of bounds for the same reason @billy mentioned

Comment: @Sedrick, I think you have misunderstood what OP is trying to achieve.  All three loops are needed.  The issue is just that `x.length` should read `x[0].length`.

Comment: You are right. I read wrong.

Comment: @billy.mccarthy  ahhh ok i see the issue now, if i replace x.length with 2, it works fine The only issue now is say if the input changes to like int[][] x= {{1,2,9},{3,4,5},{6,7}}; or int[][] x= {{1},{3,4,5},{6,7}};

Comment: @Java_Beginner as Dawood mentioned you should try to use the .length variable on the array as this will tell you the max size for each of the arrays being used this will allow your code to be a bit more dynamic in how it iterates over each. Note that length is always one larger than the index.You may find this easier to achieve with a fourth loop reason being you need one loop top tell you the size of the first array x.length, one for each of the inner arrays x[0][i].length, x[0][j].length, x[0][k].length

Comment: @Java_Beginner I have added an answer to show how to do this but really depends on how you see this code evolving, will you always only have three arrays in the first array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing i < x.length, try i < x[0].length The length of x is 3 and that of the first element is 2. Hence, the out of bounds exception. Also, it might be a good idea to get x[1].length and x[2].length instead of hard coding 3 and 2.
Try:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[][] x= {{1,2},{3,4,5},{6,7}};
        for (int i = 0; i < x[0].length; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < x[1].length; j++){
                for(int k = 0; k < x[2].length; k++){
                    System.out.println(x[0][i] + " " + x[1][j] + " " + x[2][k]);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code will not work for `int[][] x = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9, 10 } };`

Comment: @Amitabha Roy thats because the way my loops are set up, it only handles 3 sets or subarrays, hence the 3 nested loops. For your scenario, I would need 4 loops with each loop boundary being the number of elements in each subarray. Or you can just use the arraylist method some others have posted.

Comment: What will then be your solution for N number of loops where N being unknown in advance? The solution should support any number of loops because we are using loops.

Comment: What I put up here was a quick solution to what was asked for in the question. If the size of the array was going to be dynamic and not just 3, I am thinking a recursion procedure would work best.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for something complex written in Java 8? Here it is:

```
package com.test;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

public class ArrayPrint {

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        int[][] x = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 } };

        Stream<List<Integer>> inputs = null;

        for (int[] set : x) {
            List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            Collections.addAll(list, Arrays.stream(set).boxed().toArray(Integer[]::new));
            if (inputs == null) {
                inputs = Stream.of(list);
            } else {
                inputs = Stream.concat(inputs, Stream.of(list));
            }
        }

        Stream<List<List<Integer>>> listified = inputs.filter(Objects::nonNull).filter(input -> !input.isEmpty())
                .map(l -> l.stream().map(o -> new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(o))).collect(Collectors.toList()));

        List<List<Integer>> combinations = listified.reduce((input1, input2) -> {
            List<List<Integer>> merged = new ArrayList<>();
            input1.forEach(permutation1 -> input2.forEach(permutation2 -> {
                List<Integer> combination = new ArrayList<>();
                combination.addAll(permutation1);
                combination.addAll(permutation2);
                merged.add(combination);
            }));
            return merged;
        }).orElse(null);

        combinations.forEach(System.out::println);
    }

}
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 6]
[1, 3, 7]
[1, 4, 6]
[1, 4, 7]
[1, 5, 6]
[1, 5, 7]
[2, 3, 6]
[2, 3, 7]
[2, 4, 6]
[2, 4, 7]
[2, 5, 6]
[2, 5, 7]
```

With `int[][] x = { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 }, { 8, 9, 10 } };`, Output:

```
[1, 3, 6, 8]
[1, 3, 6, 9]
[1, 3, 6, 10]
[1, 3, 7, 8]
[1, 3, 7, 9]
[1, 3, 7, 10]
[1, 4, 6, 8]
[1, 4, 6, 9]
[1, 4, 6, 10]
[1, 4, 7, 8]
[1, 4, 7, 9]
[1, 4, 7, 10]
[1, 5, 6, 8]
[1, 5, 6, 9]
[1, 5, 6, 10]
[1, 5, 7, 8]
[1, 5, 7, 9]
[1, 5, 7, 10]
[2, 3, 6, 8]
[2, 3, 6, 9]
[2, 3, 6, 10]
[2, 3, 7, 8]
[2, 3, 7, 9]
[2, 3, 7, 10]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 9]
[2, 4, 6, 10]
[2, 4, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 7, 9]
[2, 4, 7, 10]
[2, 5, 6, 8]
[2, 5, 6, 9]
[2, 5, 6, 10]
[2, 5, 7, 8]
[2, 5, 7, 9]
[2, 5, 7, 10]
```

Thus, this code can handle **any two dimensional** integer array.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my suggestion from the comments try this code and look at the changes to each for loop. Instead of iterating over predetermined size like `for(int k = 0; k < 2; k++)` We instead iterate based on the size of the array as follows `for(int k = 0; k < x[1].length; k++)`

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    int[][] x = { { 1, 2, 3}, { 3, 4, 5 }, { 6, 7 } };

    for (int j = 0; j < x[0].length; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < x[1].length; k++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < x[2].length; l++) {
                System.out.println(x[0][j] + " " + x[1][k] + " " + x[2][l]);
            }
        }
    }

}
```

As long as your outer array only contains three arrays you can do as shown. Otherwise you will need to be a bit more sophisticated with you loops and not hardcode the specific index like  `for(int k = 0; k < x[0].length; k++)` Here we are directly coding index 0.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You could always declare an array of objects and cast to the data-type of your choice like this.

```
public class PrintArray{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Object[][] myArray = {{1, 2, 3},
                              {4, 5, null},
                              {7, 8, null}};

        for(int x = 0; x < myArray.length; x++){
            for(int y = 0; y < 3; y++){
                if(myArray[x][y] != null){
                    System.out.print((int)myArray[x][y]);
                }
            }
        System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

I hope this helps